# Python app-level document/record locking (eg. for MongoDB)

Tags: python, multithreading, mongodb, locking

### Introduction

MongoDB does not provide means to lock a document (like SELECT FOR UPDATE in RDBMS).

There is recommended approach to [Isolate Sequence of Operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/isolate-sequence-of-operations/), which is sometimes called *optimistic locking*, but there are scenarios when this approach seems to be overly complicated or even inefficient (that is why *pessimistic locks* are still in use).

### Task

I'd like to implement generic document locking at application level. Assuming I have only one application working with collection. And my application is *multi-threaded*.

Usage scenario:

```
with DocumentLock(doc_id):
  # make sure no other thread interferes
  doc=db.doc_collection.find_one(doc_id)
  ... # analyse and update the document
  db.doc_collection.save(doc)
```

### Question

What solution would you recommend for the task?

Comment: Perhaps you should try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for code review.

Comment: Document locking is common task/question asked on SO. But there is no solution proposed at application level. I do have one solution but I'd like to hear other thoughts. I have removed my solution from the question so it complies to SO rules.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my DocumentLock class:

```
class DocumentLock(object):

  _lock=RLock() # protects access to _locks dictionary
  _locks=WeakValueDictionary()

  def __init__(self, doc_id):
    self.doc_id=doc_id

  def __enter__(self):
    with self._lock:
      self.lock=self._locks.get(self.doc_id)
      if self.lock is None:
        self._locks[self.doc_id]=self.lock=RLock()
    self.lock.acquire()

  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    self.lock.release()
    self.lock=None # make available for garbage collection
```

So basically I have a dictionary of RLocks, one RLock per accessed document. I use weak references to get rid of unused locks.

DocumentLock can be subclassed for every collection (or table) that needs record locking.

This all seems to work (although not tested under concurrency) but I'm not sure there are no weaknesses in this approach or if there's a better one.